# Controlling history api in javascript beetween multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

could somebody help me please to resolve issue with multiple pages history control. For example sometimes I have duplicates in history of the same page and sometimes I want to skip some pages. What I want to do is, to have customized and organized history of my pages, the way I need it, sometimes to control history after user is logged out. I was reading about push states:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);});

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
updateContent(event.state);});
```

But that mostly done for same page creation with different content. I need to control my history of multiple pages.

Comment: You should consider using `localStorage` or `cookies` so that data persists even when user closes the tab or uses multiple tabs or has logged out. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I guess I was looking into another direction, thx much @kaushik94.